# Xamarin Binding Android Library, Buid Failure

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I'm developing a camera project, I created a Bindings Library (Android) project and imported the ".jar" file to "Jars" folder. Build output:

```
E:\Examples\03Android\BindingsLibrary\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Hikvision.Audio.AudioEngineCallBack.cs(104,77,104,95): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IAudioBaseCallBack' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Hikvision.Audio' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

E:\Examples\03Android\BindingsLibrary\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Videogo.DNS.DClass.cs(50,30,50,44): error CS0115: 'DClass.DClassMnemonic.ThresholdClass': no suitable method found to override

E:\Examples\03Android\BindingsLibrary\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Videogo.DNS.DNAMERecord.cs(12,30,12,39): warning CS0109: The member 'DNAMERecord.class_ref' does not hide an inherited member. The new keyword is not required.
```

... Etc.
How to solve these errors and warnings?

Comment: please can you mark my post as the correct answer for this question? Its a StackOverflow goo practice. Really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

From de documentation:

> When you are generating Java Bindings, there are several common error
>   scenarios that you may run into. This article lists these scenarios,
>   explains the possible causes, and offers suggestions for resolving the
>   errors.

So this ins't an automatic blind process.

From what I see, you will need to [troubleshoot](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/) itself.